# Is it possibe to include the file to "ShellExecute" within a dll? If so, What should be the file location in "ShellExecute"?

Tags: c++

I have a C++ dll that will run ShellExecute() to open a file. This runs fine with my file in "Desktop". I would like to embed this file within my dll, and have the ShellExecute() call this file.

Is this possible? If so, What should I point the file location to in ShellExecute()?

Note: My file is jScript. Any other way to execute jscript from c++ dll would work for me too.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible directly as stated.

You could embed the file in your DLL and write it out temporarily to `%TEMP%` and execute it from there.

Comment: Thanks. Could you point to some examples or any resource which elaborates on this.

Answer (score 0):

You could embed a js engine into your dll like [v8](https://v8.dev/). Executing files from memory with ShellExecute is not possible.